# Babel node inspect async/await disordered trace

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, async-await, babeljs, trace

There is an back-end application that uses transformed code by babel. babel-node is to run the code. I trace it by inspection at VS code. It seems working unless async/await construction. Here it begins to jump all over the code and also runtime code. For React it worked well. It logical but needless I need to follow one by one.

```js
(async function() {
  console.log('Promises')
  const a = await fetchPromise(5)
  const b = await fetchPromise(6)
  const c = await fetchPromise(7)
  console.log(a, b, c)
})()
```

There is a launch config. Node modules have to be skipped.

```
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "/home/vs-digifoon/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/npx",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "babel-node"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.js",
        },
```

Comment: There is a github issue without a resolution. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45345

Comment: There is babel alternative https://swc.rs/

Answer (score 0):

It has to be compiled for the specific platform. It works for back-end well.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```